# What does the -m32 compiler flag achieve?

Tags: gcc, compiler-flags

In the code for building applications for a vendor driver, I see the following directive:

```
SAMPLE_CFLAGS   = -Wall -m32
```

I am not sure I quite understand what the option `-m32` stands for?

I googled for the same and the closest I got was the following link, which refers to the flag `-m64` but provides no description:

[CPP/C++ Compiler Flags and Options](https://caiorss.github.io/C-Cpp-Notes/compiler-flags-options.html)

Can someone provide an explanation?

Comment: It means to build for a 32-bit target. Some distributions of gcc support building for 32-bit and 64-bit targets from the same implementation

Comment: @M.M is there any documentation that explains this flag? Any links?

Comment: google `gcc m32`